# Understanding TestSuites

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng

`TestNG 6.8.8`

I have the following interface:

```
public interface MyInterface{
    /**
    * Some contract
    **/
    public String convert(String arg);
}
```

Now I have a bunch of `MyInterface` implementations: `MyInterface1Impl`, `MyInterface2Impl`, `MyInterface3Impl`, etc...

The issue is that I want to test the general contract defined in `JavaDoc` as well as details of a specific implementation. An I'd write something like this:

```
public class MyInterfacecontractTestSuite{

    @Test(dataProvider="someDataProvider")
    public void testContract(MyInterface mi, String arg){
        //test
    }
}
```

and, for instance

```
public class MyInterface1ImplTest{
    //test cases for the implementation MyInterface1Impl
}
```

But it looks a little bit messy in that the cases for `MyInterface1Impl` are not all in the `MyInterface1ImplTest` class which might be confusing for a bit.

But putting a duplicate test case for the general contract in every implementation test class is weird as well.

So, I'm not qiute sure if I'm on the right way. Maybe there's some better solution for testing such contracts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not having something like:

```
public abstract class MyInterfacecontractTestSuite {

    @Test(dataProvider="someDataProvider")
    public void testContract(String arg) {
        //test against getMi()
    }

    public abstract MyInterface getMi();
}

public class MyInterface1ImplTest extends MyInterfacecontractTestSuite {

    private MyInterface1Impl mi; // init somewhere

    public MyInterface getMi() {
        return mi;
    }

    //test cases for the implementation MyInterface1Impl
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about this kind of idea, but rejected it. What to do if an implementation implements more than one interface which also is required to test some basic contracts? I thought that might be a problem... But anyway, it looks better.

Comment: Maybe you can try to implement a Factory (http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#factories) and generate MyInterfacecontractTestSuite (and other interface related test classes) depending on what interface your implementation is implementing. But it could more complicated than duplication.